# Threaded Loop Crashes After 20 Minutes (RPi/GPIO)

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, raspberry-pi, gpio

Looking for help to make this code work (better)? The program freezes up after the loop has been running for a while (15-20 minutes). I've been told by a few users that synchronization using `time.sleep()` is not a good idea and I'm wondering if that's my problem. Please use my code as the example when you reply because I'm a novice when it comes to Python. The simpler the better.

The code should play a video loop as a default and when a push button is triggered (RPi/GPIO) a different video plays. Once that video is finished it goes back to the default looped video. I'm using OMXPlayer as you can see.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import subprocess
import time
import thread

GPIO.setmode (GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings (False)

GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN)  # Button 1
GPIO.setup(9, GPIO.IN)  # Button 2
GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.IN) # Button 3
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.IN) # Button 4
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN) # Button 5
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN) # Button 6
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.IN) # Button 7

video_playing = False # Loop flag initial status

def welcome_loop():
    global playProcess
    while True:
        x = 1
        if not video_playing:
                print "Play Welcome Video"
                time.sleep(.05)
                playProcess=subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer','-b','Desktop/videos/loop/loop.mp4'],
                                                 stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                                 stderr=subprocess.PIPE,close_fds=True)
                time.sleep(24) # Length of video
        x += 1

def videos():
    #initialise a previous input variable to 0 (assume button not pressed last)
    prev_input = 0
    global video_playing
    while True:
        button1 = GPIO.input(27)
        if ((not prev_input) and button1):
                video_playing = True  # Set the flag (loop pauses)
                print "Stop Welcome Video"
                time.sleep(.5)
                playProcess.stdin.write('q') # Stop video      
                time.sleep(.5)
                print "Play Martin Lab - Reel"
                martinlab_reel=subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer','-b','Desktop/videos/martinlab_reel.mp4'],
                                                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE,close_fds=True)
                time.sleep(30) # Length of video
                martinlab_reel.stdin.write('q')
                video_playing = False  # Unset the flag (loop continues)

        #update previous input
        prev_input = button1
        #slight pause to debounce
        time.sleep(.25)

        button2 = GPIO.input(9)
        if ((not prev_input) and button2):
                video_playing = True  # Set the flag (loop pauses)
                print "Stop Welcome Video"
                time.sleep(.5)
                playProcess.stdin.write('q') # Stop video
                time.sleep(.5)
                print "Play Shoppingcart"
                shoppingcart=subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer','-b','Desktop/videos/shoppingcart.mp4'],
                                                    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,close_fds=True)
                time.sleep(111) # Length of video
                shoppingcart.stdin.write('q')
                video_playing = False  # Unset the flag (loop continues)

        #update previous input
        prev_input = button2
        #slight pause to debounce
        time.sleep(.25)

        button3 = GPIO.input(10)
        if ((not prev_input) and button3):
                video_playing = True  # Set the flag (loop pauses)
                print "Stop Welcome Video"
                time.sleep(.5)
                playProcess.stdin.write('q') # Stop video
                time.sleep(.5)
                print "Play Dodgeballs"
                dodgeballs=subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer','-b','Desktop/videos/dodgeballs.mp4'],
                                                    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,close_fds=True)
                time.sleep(102) # Length of video
                dodgeballs.stdin.write('q')
                video_playing = False  # Unset the flag (loop continues)

        #update previous input
        prev_input = button3
        #slight pause to debounce
        time.sleep(.25)

        button4 = GPIO.input(11)
        if ((not prev_input) and button4):
                video_playing = True  # Set the flag (loop pauses)
                print "Stop Welcome Video"
                time.sleep(.5)
                playProcess.stdin.write('q') # Stop video
                time.sleep(.5)
                print "Play Hidden Camera"
                hiddencamera=subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer','-b','Desktop/videos/hiddencamera.mov'],
                                                    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,close_fds=True)
                time.sleep(37) # Length of video
                hiddencamera.stdin.write('q') # Stop video
                video_playing = False  # Unset the flag (loop continues)

        #update previous input
        prev_input = button4
        #slight pause to debounce
        time.sleep(.25)

        button5 = GPIO.input(17)
        if ((not prev_input) and button5):
                video_playing = True  # Set the flag (loop pauses)
                print "Stop Welcome Video"
                time.sleep(.5)
                playProcess.stdin.write('q') # Stop video      
                time.sleep(.5)
                print "Play Light of Human Kindness"
                lohk_reel=subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer','-b','Desktop/videos/LOHK_short.mp4'],
                                                    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,close_fds=True)
                time.sleep(83) # Length of video
                lohk_reel.stdin.write('q')
                video_playing = False  # Unset the flag (loop continues)

        #update previous input
        prev_input = button5
        #slight pause to debounce
        time.sleep(.25)

        button6 = GPIO.input(22)
        if ((not prev_input) and button6):
                video_playing = True  # Set the flag (loop pauses)
                print "Stop Welcome Video"
                time.sleep(.5)
                playProcess.stdin.write('q') # Stop video      
                time.sleep(.5)
                print "Play RVA Makerfest"
                rva_makerfest=subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer','-b','Desktop/videos/rva_makerfest.mp4'],
                                                    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,close_fds=True)
                time.sleep(101) # Length of video
                rva_makerfest.stdin.write('q')
                video_playing = False  # Unset the flag (loop continues)

        #update previous input
        prev_input = button6
        #slight pause to debounce
        time.sleep(.25)

        button7 = GPIO.input(27)
        if ((not prev_input) and button7):
                video_playing = True  # Set the flag (loop pauses)
                print "Stop Welcome Video"
                time.sleep(.5)
                playProcess.stdin.write('q') # Stop video      
                time.sleep(.5)
                print "Play PartyBot - Reel"
                partybot_reel=subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer','-b','Desktop/videos/partybot_reel.mov'],
                                                    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,close_fds=True)
                time.sleep(61) # Length of video
                partybot_reel.stdin.write('q')
                video_playing = False  # Unset the flag (loop continues)

        #update previous input
        prev_input = button7
        #slight pause to debounce
        time.sleep(.25)

thread.start_new_thread( videos, () ) # Videos thread
thread.start_new_thread( welcome_loop, () ) # Loop thread

while True:
    pass

GPIO.cleanup() #Reset GPIOs
```

**ERROR (After 2-hour run):**

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function welcome_loop at 0xb6c8b3b0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./labmural2.py", line 32, in welcome_loop
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,close_fds=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1153, in _execute_child
    self.pid = os.fork()
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

**HEAPY RETURN VALUES (Memory Useage):**

```
Partition of a set of 26904 objects. Total size = 1957148 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
  0  12601  47   786404  40    786404  40 str
  1   6274  23   254548  13   1040952  53 tuple
  2   1756   7   126432   6   1167384  60 types.CodeType
  3     80   0   122944   6   1290328  66 dict of module
  4    203   1   108292   6   1398620  71 dict of type
  5   1709   6   102540   5   1501160  77 function
  6    121   0    98540   5   1599700  82 dict (no owner)
  7    203   1    90232   5   1689932  86 type
  8    121   0    70316   4   1760248  90 dict of class
  9   1054   4    42160   2   1802408  92 __builtin__.wrapper_descriptor
```

**free -m**:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           247        159         87          0          7         75
-/+ buffers/cache:         76        170
Swap:           99          8         91
```

Comment: Is it *crashing* (is there a traceback?) or is the program hanging? If it's the latter, have you tried adding any debugging code (like `print` statements) to figure out exactly where its freezing?

Comment: It's just hanging. The screen goes black in between when the video loop restarts. No errors. That's a good idea though. I'll try that. Because I'm having difficulty understanding the threading/queue suggestion. But not giving up!

Comment: I removed the '-b' variable from the omxplayer launch command which creates a black background behind the video and it is doing great so far. I'll just have to add a black background canvas with pygame or something if this works. Hopefully we are home free! I'll let you know.

Comment: So it ran for about 2 hours this time and then I received the error above.

Comment: Looks like you're running out of memory. Monitor your memory usage as the process. Does Python's memory usage continously grow? Or maybe the subprocesses you're starting aren't ever exiting, and you're just starting more and more of them?

Comment: It doesn't continue to grow from what I can tell. I just installed and am running Heapy from Guppy as the program runs and it gives me the above returns. I'm also refreshing using the command `free -m` and those values are below it.

Comment: Why are you piping all of the stdout/stderr?

Comment: @GP89 That's just the only way I've gotten it to work. It's working great now that I made the change in comments for the answer below.

Comment: It can cause you problems if you use a `PIPE` and don't read from the them. If the process fills the pipe buffer [it will deadlock](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait). If you're just trying to silence the output, instead send it to `open(os.devnull, 'wb')`

Comment: I think that's actually your problem, the processes are getting deadlocked and not ending

Answer (score 0):

Use threading and Queue instead of thread and global variables.

Comment: I'll have to look up how to do that. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you're running out of memory or available processes due to the way that you're starting processes and waiting for them to finish.  After your program has been running for some time, use `ps -AF` to check for the number of processes that are running.

Imagine the video you're attempting to play runs for 9 seconds instead of 10 seconds.  This will result in the system attempting to start the video playing again before the first one has finished due to the `time.sleep()` calls.  Eventually you end up with many overlapping video players attempting to run the same video and so exhaust memory or the number of processes allowed by the operating system.

I suggest to change the play/wait constructs to something like this:

```
playProcess=subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer','-b','Desktop/videos/loop/loop.mp4'],
                                                 stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                                 stderr=subprocess.PIPE,close_fds=True)
playProcess.wait() # Wait for video to finish playing
```

Comment: Thanks @Austin Phillips. It seems to be working already. Using `free -m` it's looking like I am not losing memory. I'll let it go for a while and let you know what happens. Fingers crossed!

Comment: After 10 minutes of running the video stops playing and just hangs. No errors or traceback. Dang I thought we had it. What if I use `time.sleep()` until a little after the video is finished?

Comment: Nope. That doesn't work, using `time.sleep()` does create multiple processes. Maybe there's a way to get `playProcess.wait()` to work...hmmm

Comment: `playProcess.communicate()` seems to be doing the trick. Not losing memory, creating duplicate processes, or hanging. I'll let you know how long it goes and if we have a winner.

Comment: It's been going 3 hours flawlessly! I think we are good! I'm going to run it all day Monday just to be sure. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I've been asked to add the ability to stop a video mid-play and play a different video. I've tried creating another thread which kills the other, but no luck. Also, can't stop a video because of the time.sleep command. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

i have this problem and when check open file in linux i understand increase number of files according to time. so after number of file arrive to "ulimit -n" script stop. My solution was increase number of open file in linux, and i increase number of file to 1,000,000 by use below link:

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/

but basically solution is prevent to open a lot of file.
(i just use a class to read temperature with, and i don't know why increase number of files according to time)

Comment: As someone familiar with Linux, the description seems adequate.  This is probably the wrong answer as there is probably a leak, but that's a reason to vote down not flag